# Is it possible to run Selenium test with Phing?

Tags: selenium, automation, phing

I don't see a Task for it, and haven't been able to find any documentation so far.

Any help would be appreciated!

Thanks,

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I am not sure what your approach to executing selenium tests is (there are different ways) but probably the most common one would be through PHPUnit which has API for running Selenium tests (see the [PHPUnit documentation](http://www.phpunit.de/manual/current/en/selenium.html)). And then there is a support for running PHPUnit tests (see the [Phing documentation](http://www.phing.info/docs/guide/stable/chapters/appendixes/AppendixC-OptionalTasks.html#PHPUnitTask)).

It should be relatively easy to run your tests using those two. However if your approach is different don't forget there's always the possibility to execute arbitrary shell command from Phing (using the exec task) which should allow for whatever you need to do.

Comment: Thanks, that's helpful. Now to setup PHPUnit on that application ;)